# How to unit test the multi/part form-data using glassfish jersey?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jersey, glassfish, multipartform-data

I am trying to pass multiparform data fields `Map<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>>`, the input I get from the rest API to the manager class that accepts the multipart fields as a input and read it and perform the required action.

```
JsonNode data = objectMapper.readTree(requestFields.get(REQUEST).get(0).getValueAs(InputStream.class));
```

Assuming I always get the only one element only. The method works when I hit a postman request.

But when I am trying to unit test the manager class that accepts the field of the multipart form data throws an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity instance does not contain the unconverted content.

    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.BodyPart.getEntityAs(BodyPart.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart.getValueAs(FormDataBodyPart.java:291)
    at com.confluxsys.iam.adc.core.impl.request.RequestManagerImpl.createRequest(RequestManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.confluxsys.iam.adc.util.request.TestRequestManagerV2.createRequestV2(TestRequestManagerV2.java:154)
```

**Test class code -->**

```
String data = "{"menu":{"id":"file","value":"File","popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"},{"value":"Open","onclick":"OpenDoc()"},{"value":"Close","onclick":"CloseDoc()"}]}}}";    
InputStream jsonStream;
            try (FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()) {
                FormDataBodyPart form1 = new FormDataBodyPart();
                jsonStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes());
                form1.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
                form1.setValue(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, jsonStream);
                form1.setName("part-config");
                form1.getHeaders().add("Content-Length", String.valueOf(config.getBytes().length));
    
    
                formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(form1);
              requestManager.createRequest(formDataMultiPart.getFields());
            }
```

**Main class code --->**

```
public void createRequest(Map<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> requestFields) throws SystemFailureException, com.confluxsys.iap.config.util.ObjectNotFoundException {
if (!requestFields.containsKey(REQUEST)) {
            logger.error("Request json is not passed in the request payload");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The 'request' body part is missing in the payload.");
        }

        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new objectMapper() ;
            //as data [request] will always be sent assuming it will be present at first location
            JsonNode data = objectMapper.readTree(requestFields.get(REQUEST).get(0).getValueAs(InputStream.class));
/*validation after reading */
}catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemFailureException("Error occured while creating request .Rolling back all operation .cause : ", e);
        }
}
```

Can anyone suggest is there any way I can unit test this class?

Library --> org.glassfish.jersey 2.35

Comment: Try using the JerseyTest framework and run integration test. It might be easier

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I want to test my  manager layer not the service layer. Can I do that with jersey test framework? And also it will be helpful if you can provide some resources.